# RewriteRule for article.php?id=1 to name-of-printer

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So we recently got a website of a client which was being developed custom for our client and they basically have non-friendly URLs "article.php?id=1". I am trying to make them SEO friendly and while I am creating the new URL I cannot make their old one automatically redirect to what I just created.

I have tried the following with no luck:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^articulo.php?id=1$ "xerox-phaser-3020bi" [NC,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^xerox-phaser-3260dni$ /articulo.php?id=2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^xerox-phaser-33dn$ articulo.php?id=3 [L]
```

As you notice I am manually creating the URL for each product (only about 38) and since the app does not print category.php?name=nameofcategory&article.php?id=1 I figured this would be the best way to do friendly URLs.

What I want is so that when someone clicks in our website for /article.php?id=1 product they are taken to the friendly URL such as : /xerox-phaser-3260dni

Thanks!

**Edit:**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=1$ 
RewriteRule ^articulo\.php$ /xerox-phaser-3260dni/? [R=301,L]
```

This code redirects but does not show the page when accessing the friendly URL.

Answer (score 2):

Your method doesn't work because your URLs include symbols like `?`. You need to use `{QUERY_STRING}`.

Try the following:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} article.php?id=1$ 
RewriteRule (.*) /xerox-phaser-3260dni/? [R=301,L]
```

Don’t forget to add a `?` at the end of the redirected URLs as that is needed so that the query string does not appear on the end of the URL.

Make sure you clear your cache before testing this.

Comment: Unfortunately this suggestion does not redirect or return the right page when accessing the friendly URL